# Are there any benefits to removing unused script files in a web site/project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, deployment

VS Web sites/projects come loaded with several .js files, most of which I don't use (e.g., I use a CDN for newer versions of jQuery and jQuery-UI). I know it's safe to remove these unneeded .js files from my projects, but is there any benefit from doing so? Are they deployed to the web server if left alone?

Comment: I would say that, in general, removing unused files certainly improves comprehensibility for future maintainers of the code.

Comment: Also good for security - a classic attack vector is through old versions.

Comment: Yes. If you're using Visual Studio with a "Web Site" they're deployed when using WebDeploy. Also, the more important aspect here is what apsillers said.

Answer (score -2):

yes, it's take time to load and cause to reduce the performance , other way to reduce it you can compile multiple js files in to one.please refer
https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript
http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange